# MySQL Locking System

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building a huge scale of database with many transactions there. (Insert, Update, Select) with MySQL MyISAM

And I'm considering to use LOCK TABLE AND UNLOCK TABLE for the sensitive tables. What will happen if :

User A has an update process (Lock the table first) and while still in process, User B and User C trying to access the same table and row (whether it's update/select).

- Will B and C immediately get the SQL error about tables being locked?
- Does MySQL has lock timeout before it returns the error? If there's a lock timeout, how do I check the lock timeout in my server?
- Any better solution than locking the tables? We are considering of creating a table for job queue. But I think the performance will be really bad.

This table is really sensitive, and it will messed up if I can't prevent this

Thanks for your answer

Comment: sounds to me you're better of using `InnoDB` engine since it supports transactions and row level locking

Comment: MyISAM cannot do transactions. I suggest you use MariaDB or Percona which is more stable and has better locking functionality by default. You don't have to do any manual locking. Your Backup possibility is always the `backlog` and the replications.

Comment: Do you need to know about engine types and their quirks or do you want to check what's the best method to implement a job queue according to your specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - B & C are blocked until the timeout expires. I can't find the timeout setting for MyISAM right now - it's set in mysqld.conf for InnoDB.

As others have said - InnoDB is a better engine if you need transaction support.

However, consider whether you really need locks at all. They create unpredictable bottlenecks in performance, especially in systems with many concurrent users. While table-level locks shouldn't lead to the dreaded [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) scenario, table-level locks mean that only one process can use the table at any time; if each database operation takes 1 second (not unreasonable in huge databases), any more than 2 concurrent users of the system will notice performance degradation; 10 concurrent users would see the system become very slow, especially if you have to join across multiple tables.

Transactions are a much better solution in most cases.

Comment: Hi Neville, thanks for your answer. What does the "B & C are blocked" refer to? Will it be on queue (A will run, and then B and C)? Or are the transaction will be blocked and returns the error?

Comment: They will wait until the locks are released. There doesn't appear to be a timeout setting for MyISAM, so they could wait forever...

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `MyISAM` storage engine if you want to scale more efficiently and deal with concurrency problems. The main reason to choose `InnoDB` instead of `MyISAM` is that `MyISAM` use per table locks (which will become the bottleneck of your performance), while `InnoDB` implements `MVCC` (multiversion concurrency control) which means locking at row level.

Also `MyISAM` does not support transactions and needs manual repair in case of table curruption.

Answer (score 0):

To get good performance with transaction support better to use INNODB instead of MYISAM.
INNODB works on row level locking. Same time multiple users can access the table for changing different records.

[Read here for INNODB locking mechanism](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)

[Read here for locking issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html)